# Cannot install python arcade on mac

Tags: python, arcade

I was trying to do something with python, so I tried to install arcade. Just `pip install arcade` didn't work and I've tried other stuff too like following [this](https://arcade-pk.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation_mac.html) link. None of it worked, It always gave me the same error. This is the whole log.

```
Collecting arcade
  Using cached arcade-2.5.2-py3-none-any.whl (38.3 MB)
Collecting numpy==1.19.2
  Using cached numpy-1.19.2.zip (7.3 MB)
  Installing build dependencies: started
  Installing build dependencies: finished with status 'done'
  Getting requirements to build wheel: started
  Getting requirements to build wheel: finished with status 'done'
    Preparing wheel metadata: started
    Preparing wheel metadata: still running...
    Preparing wheel metadata: finished with status 'done'
Collecting pytiled-parser==0.9.4a3
  Using cached pytiled_parser-0.9.4a3-py3-none-any.whl (15 kB)
Collecting pillow~=8.0
  Using cached Pillow-8.1.0-cp39-cp39-macosx_10_10_x86_64.whl (2.2 MB)
Collecting pyglet<2,>=1.5.11
  Using cached pyglet-1.5.14-py3-none-any.whl (1.1 MB)
Collecting pymunk~=5.7
  Using cached pymunk-5.7.0-py2.py3-none-macosx_10_13_x86_64.whl (201 kB)
Collecting cffi!=1.13.1
  Using cached cffi-1.14.4-cp39-cp39-macosx_10_9_x86_64.whl (177 kB)
Collecting pyyaml~=5.3
  Using cached PyYAML-5.4-cp39-cp39-macosx_10_9_x86_64.whl (259 kB)
Collecting shapely~=1.7
  Using cached Shapely-1.7.1.tar.gz (383 kB)

    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /Users/AaronKanaron/PycharmProjects/arcadeTest/venv/bin/python -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/vq/283xsscx57v67tffn6yn4_s80000gp/T/pip-install-dncw7kpb/shapely_c0fed3cf0b1b47b7b3c8397e61f3a6f7/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/vq/283xsscx57v67tffn6yn4_s80000gp/T/pip-install-dncw7kpb/shapely_c0fed3cf0b1b47b7b3c8397e61f3a6f7/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base /private/var/folders/vq/283xsscx57v67tffn6yn4_s80000gp/T/pip-pip-egg-info-4y1krwzl
         cwd: /private/var/folders/vq/283xsscx57v67tffn6yn4_s80000gp/T/pip-install-dncw7kpb/shapely_c0fed3cf0b1b47b7b3c8397e61f3a6f7/
    Complete output (12 lines):
    Failed `CDLL(/Library/Frameworks/GEOS.framework/Versions/Current/GEOS)`
    Failed `CDLL(/opt/local/lib/libgeos_c.dylib)`
    Failed `CDLL(/usr/local/lib/libgeos_c.dylib)`
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/private/var/folders/vq/283xsscx57v67tffn6yn4_s80000gp/T/pip-install-dncw7kpb/shapely_c0fed3cf0b1b47b7b3c8397e61f3a6f7/setup.py", line 85, in <module>
        from shapely._buildcfg import geos_version_string, geos_version, \
      File "/private/var/folders/vq/283xsscx57v67tffn6yn4_s80000gp/T/pip-install-dncw7kpb/shapely_c0fed3cf0b1b47b7b3c8397e61f3a6f7/shapely/_buildcfg.py", line 190, in <module>
        lgeos = load_dll('geos_c', fallbacks=alt_paths)
      File "/private/var/folders/vq/283xsscx57v67tffn6yn4_s80000gp/T/pip-install-dncw7kpb/shapely_c0fed3cf0b1b47b7b3c8397e61f3a6f7/shapely/_buildcfg.py", line 162, in load_dll
        raise OSError(
    OSError: Could not find library geos_c or load any of its variants ['/Library/Frameworks/GEOS.framework/Versions/Current/GEOS', '/opt/local/lib/libgeos_c.dylib', '/usr/local/lib/libgeos_c.dylib']
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

It can't find setup.py, and what I've searched nothing has helped me so far. So if any of you could help me with this problem it would be fantastic.

Comment: You have an error while installing Shapely: "*OSError: Could not find library geos_c or load any of its variants*". Have you tried `brew install geos`?

Answer (score 0):

You have to install the library GEOS on your system. Run this command - `brew install geos`.

If you don't have brew, you can download it here: https://brew.sh

On ubuntu, you can do `$ sudo apt-get install libgeos-dev`.